# Does AS3 support functions when using the String.replace() with a RegEx?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Can you place a function where the replacement text goes in ActionScript?

For example can you take this:

```
string = string.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, "word");
```

And do this:

```
string = string.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function(m){ 
   return /^[A-Z]/.test(m) ? "Word" : "word" 
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Function/<anonymous>(). Expected 1, got 3.
    at String$/_replace()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more info [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29).

So while this works in JavaScript:

```
string = string.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function(m){ 
   return /^[A-Z]/.test(m) ? "Word" : "word" 
});
```

We would have to remove the parameter and use the arguments object available to all functions like so:

```
string = string.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function():String {
   var match:String = arguments[0];
   //var matchIndex:int = arguments[arguments.length-2];
   //var updatedString:String = arguments[arguments.length-1];

   return /^[A-Z]/.test(match) ? "Word" : "word" 
});
```

Here is more description on these parameters:

*When you specify a function as the repl, the replace() method passes
the following parameters to the function:*

- The matching portion of the string.
- Any captured parenthetical group matches are provided as the next arguments. The number of arguments passed this way will vary
  depending on the number of parenthetical matches. You can determine
  the number of parenthetical matches by checking arguments.length - 3
  within the function code.
- The index position in the string where the match begins.
- The complete string.